# How can you install elementary OS without installing the bootloader?

Tags: release-freya, system-installation, boot, grub

I want to install eOS but i already have an Arch install with grub2. Can i skip eOS's grub installation and use my existing one?

Comment: I think you can but I haven't tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to install grub to the partition where you install your eos. You can select grub partition while partitioning your hdd.

[image]

Then update your grub from Arch Linux using `sudo update-grub`. ([Then hide your eos grub if needed](https://askubuntu.com/a/281163/556428))

Answer (score 1):

To install elementary OS without installing the GRUB boot loader:

1. Boot up an installation media an select "Try elementary OS". This will load a live session instead of loading the installer directly.
2. Open Terminal and enter the following command. This will launch the installer with the option to not install the boot loader:

   ```
   ubiquity -b
   ```
3. Continue installation as normal. The GRUB boot loader will not be installed.

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and installed it anyways. When prompted to select the location for the bootloader I went with the same drive I'm installing to, which had Arch and grub2 in it. The installation went well, and the previous grub2 was replaced, leaving me with all my old boot options with the addition of eOS.

Comment: but it would be great if someone confirms that you can install it without installing grub

Comment: I would have suggested skipping selecting the location for the bootloader. Choose the default swap area, your root and location of home partition. When all is finished, restart your computer. If grub doesn't recognise your new OS, boot into arch and reconfigure grub from there. It should be able to recognise the new partition and create a boot entry for it